# How do I make my Javascript Clock 'live'?

Tags: javascript

I would like assistance on making this clock I created in Javascript/HTML update in real-time.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script>
    function timer() {
      var today = new Date();
      var hrs = today.getHours();
      var mins = today.getMinutes();
      var secs = today.getSeconds();
      var mili = today.getMilliseconds();

      document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML = "Since midnight, " + hrs + " hours, " + mins + " minutes,  " + secs + " seconds, and " + mili + " milliseconds have passed.";
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body onload="timer()">

  <div id="txt"></div>

  <body>
    <h1>Clock</h1>
  </body>

</html>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: use setInterval function to call timer function every second

Answer (score 1):

You should create an interval timer and just call your timer function every X milliseconds, as you are displaying millisecond precision you might want to keep this low like 100ms. I suggest using [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval) for this. Just put this in your script block:

```
setInterval(timer, 100);
```

---

Here is a full example:

```js
function timer() {
  var today = new Date();
  var hrs = today.getHours();
  var mins = today.getMinutes();
  var secs = today.getSeconds();
  var mili = today.getMilliseconds();

  document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML = "Since midnight, " + hrs + " hours, " + mins + " minutes,  " + secs + " seconds, and " + mili + " milliseconds have passed.";
}

setInterval(timer, 100);
```

```html
<div id="txt"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the setTimeout function (see [window.setTimeout](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp))

In your case:
Call the timer function and add

```
window.setTimeout(timer, 50);
```

at the very end of the function.

Example:

```js
function timer() {
  var today = new Date();
  var hrs = today.getHours();
  var mins = today.getMinutes();
  var secs = today.getSeconds();
  var mili = today.getMilliseconds();

  document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML = "Since midnight, " + hrs + " hours, " + mins + " minutes,  " + secs + " seconds, and " + mili + " milliseconds have passed.";
  
  window.setTimeout(timer, 50);
}

timer();
```

```html
<div id="txt"></div>
```

Comment: `setTimeout` will only fire once so you don't get the 'live' effect, unless you put it inside the `timer` function that is. Though I don't like the idea of that

Comment: @musefan: thats correct. but if its set within the timer function it should work. added it to the answer

Comment: Yeah, there isn't technically anything wrong with your approach, just my personal preference. And it's not my downvote by the way...

Comment: I would also suggest including a complete working example in your answer. It's always useful to have working code as it makes it much clearer as to what your suggested solution is. And I would up vote your answer if you did that!

Comment: does not care about the down vote because its still a valid approach ;)